# Trying to understand what's going on for my Java class

Tags: java, constructor

I'm trying to understand how calling the constructor works.

Say you want Time t = new(125);

What would the time be?

My logic is 125/60 = 2.088 and 125%60 is 5

So is the time 2:05?

I'm so confused any breakdown or direction to get the time with just the int would be helpful

Comment: new Time(125); would result in 2h 5m. you could have added a few print statements to check that

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's focus on your constructor:

```
public Time(int m) {
    this (m / 60, m % 60);
}
```

The input is some integer number of minutes.  To get the number of hours, excluding any minutes which do not make up a full 60 minutes, we can take `m / 60`.  Then, to get the remainder of minutes after forming as many hours as possible, we can take `m % 60`.

You might to add a `toString` method:

```
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%02d", hr) + ":" + String.format("%02d", min);
}
```

Comment: So ...based on this, 125 is 2:05 then, right? 125/60 is 2 and change, then 125/60 is 5? I just want to make sure I'm understanding my code right

Comment: That's correct.  You might want to add a `toString` method, q.v. my updated answer.